# Make media URL for images pretty WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

When I upload a file it hosts it at `/app/uploads/2016/02/placeholder1.jpg`, i've been looking but can't find anything.

If I want to host some PDF files, how do I change the path above for certain files only? As in, any file I upload will be hosted there as norm. But if I want to separately host a PDF to show someone, how can I change the url so it's like `/downloads/test.pdf/`?

I can't find any plugins for this either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default all images or .pdf files are uploaded to `wp-content/uploads/` folder when you upload via media library from admin.
If you want to upload .pdf files to specific folder, follow steps.

1) Create `downloads` (or any other name you want) in `uploads` directory.

2) Make sure to give 777 permission to `downloads` folder.

3) Use filter, `add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );` to upload pdf files.

4) Using `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter, you can change the path of the pdf files to upload in `custom_upload_filter` function.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    // Check if file extension is .pdf,and upload pdf file into downloads folder
    return $file;
}
```

For Details : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter